# matching columns in multiple table ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am a beginner in ms sql and I have two tables
First table has

```
id param1 indicator1 indicator2
1  a      1          2
2  z      3          4
2  z      7          2
3  a      8          9
4  z      7          9
5  y      9          6
```

Second table has

```
Param  Indicator
a      1
b      2
null   3
null   4
```

I want a result set which will accomplish this:

```
For each row in table 1

if( param1 is in Param column)

    print row from table 1
  else 
   if(indicator1 in indicator column_
      print row from table 1
   if(indicator2 in indicator column)
     print row from table 1
```

so resulting dataset would be

```
id param1 indicator1 indicator2
1  a      1          2
2  z      3          4
2  z      7          2
3  a      8          9
```

I want a more efficient solution then

```
select distinct id, param1, indicator1, indicator2 
from table1 t1, table2 t2   
where param1= param or indicator1 = indicator or indicator2 = indicator
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Join` to check the existence use `EXISTS` which is better in performance.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   table2 s
               WHERE  t.param1 = s.Param
                       OR t.indicator1 = s.Indicator
                       OR t.indicator2 = s.Indicator)
```

Comment: Thanks Fireblade. Can you clarifiy whether sql optimizer will stop running if param1 = Param and not check for indicator1 = indicator? I am asking this question because in my query, I had to use distinct to remove duplicate. This means that table had lot of redundant data which causes performance issue esp. in 17 million large dataset.

Comment: @Novice - The join is what creating the duplicates so you have to remove those using `Distinct` but my query will not create duplicates this will be faster

Comment: Thanks. I am running it against 17 million records to test performance. I will post the results once its over. The same query with joins took me around 2 hours 17 minutes

Comment: Fireblade - it took same time which is a bit strange as second query is actually avoiding multiple inserts and deletion of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854(v=office.12).aspx)** instead of comma separated tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, param1, indicator1, indicator2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.param1 = t2.Param OR 
                  t1.indicator1 = t2.indicator OR 
                  t1.indicator2 = t2.indicator
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
id param1 indicator1 indicator2
1  a      1          2
2  z      3          4
2  z      7          2
3  a      8          9
```

**<kbd>[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/739d3/3)</kbd>**

Answer (score -1):

SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 tbl1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 tbl2 on tbl1.param1 = tbl2.param

Comment: I think you're looking for an inner join. If you want to retrieve the results that match. If you want results that don't match on the columns such as the nulls then user LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Inner join works for 1 column but in my query, I have to match on two columns in a table

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.indicator